# Read data from .txt file and save as class variable

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a class called `ExpectedProdInfo`. This class will need to have many variables to store data, 182 to be exact. I want to keep the data stored in a `.txt` file and call a method that will read the file line by line using the first line as the first class attribute and so on.

example: `prod_info.txt` contains:

```
AAAA
BHJB
7657
.
.
.
```

Need to assign each line in order to a class attribute:

```
String attr1 = "AAAA";
String attr2 = "BHJB";
String attr3 = "7657";
.
.
.
```

If anyone new of a good way to achieve this while keeping the code easy to maintain I'd love to hear your solutions.

Comment: Class members have no order. It is not possible to identify "the first" or "the 10th" class member. You will have to store the member values with member names.

Comment: **JAXB** if the file may also be XML.With annotations on each class field like @XmlAttribute. Easy. Create an instance in java, write it to XML ("marshal") and edit the XML.

Comment: In addition to @JoopEggen comment, also see JSON and property files.  But why so many attributes in one class?  If there are logical groupings of those attributes consider composition.

Comment: A class with more than 100 attributes is never easy to maintain - except if these attributes are actually stored in an array.

Comment: It's not how creating software works! Using higher lever programming languages to solve problems is different than using spreadsheets or scientific calculator

Answer (score 0):

Check out the comments!
**!** It's not a fully functioning Java code… kinda pseudo

```
import java.xyz ... // what's needed

public class ExpectedProductInfo {

  // define 182 class variables – Very bad approach!
  private String attr1;
  private String attr2;
  private String attr3;
  /*
  .
  .
  .
  */
  private String attr182;

  // good approach: an ordered collection: index 1 hold 1st variable and so on:
  ArrayList<String> attributes = new ArrayList<>(182);

  // A better approach: a Map based collection like HashMap. So you don't need
  // to follow the order of values, you can insert, get and manipulate them
  // consistently with their keys ...


  /**
   * reads a file and put each line in the collection
   * could be called on class instance or directly on the constructor
   * @param pathToFile path to file which contains the info line by line
   */
  private void readInfoFile(String pathToFile){
    File some = new File("some.txt");

    try {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(some);

      while(sc.hasNextLine()){
        attributes.add(sc.nextLine());
      }
      sc.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  // Now the attributes contains each line as an element in order
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, will have a go at using HashMap.